What is the I in "I think therefore I am"?
Descartes famously said the above phrase but what exactly is the “I” here supposed to represent?
It surely can’t be yet another thought in your consciousness since that would imply that thoughts think which seems nonsensical. But if it’s not a thought, then what exactly does Descartes mean here by “I”?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The "I" is relatively rare and normally not involved in thinking. The "I" only comes up when we think about ourselves, that is, reflexively. For example when we read your question.
Most of my thoughts in everyday life just are. They bubble up from my unconscious and I have no idea where they come from or how they were made. I have no access to that process. We certainly feel as if we are the authors of our thoughts, but there are problems with that. If I hear my neighbour screaming in the garden, I cannot choose not to hear it and to understand it for what it is. Neither can I not choose to recognise the person as my neighbour.
Think about the last conversation you had and how you were talking about a subject. At no point do you know what the next word was going to be or even how the sentence was going to end. In a sense, you were as much listening to your own speech as your interlocutor. Of course, you have some more insights in your thought processes, but when you speak, it just bubbles up from nowhere. Yet, you feel it is still you and you will claim the authorship of your thought.
In Descartes' sentence, we have a recursive loop. It is about the experience of thinking, but arguably the experience of thinking, namely the realisation I think, is a thought in itself. This thought also bubbled up, ready-made, from your unconsciousness.
Just another thought.
You said: It surely can’t be yet another thought in your consciousness since that would imply that thoughts think which seems nonsensical. No. Thoughts don't think, they just are. In the Humean sense, where thoughts are seens as perceptions, you are a bundle of perceptions. You are just the emotions, perceptions and thoughts.

+1 The point that our/my thoughts just bubble up and we don't know whence they came, or -- if there is a central controller inside or behind them, what that might be, was made extremely forcefully in various places in the the Zhuangzi (~300 BC). It's also a core aspect of his philosophy of life. E.g. https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&id=2725 (old Legge translation is a bit crummy but overall ok).

Yes, but I am in two minds when it comes to introspection. It can seem very helpful but at the same time I am very mindful of how intuitions can lead us astray... Nice references to Taoism. I once wanted to study classical Chinese, just to read those texts in the original... This website has Wenzi but untranslated. Very interesting text, though apparently the authenticity is controversial...

The "I" means the entity experiencing the thought, and under some readings, the entity causing the thought.
Indeed, the argument has been critiqued as presupposing the "I" and not being careful enough about the distinction between the thinking and the experience of thinking.
See Friedrich Nietzshe, Beyond Good and Evil (as translated by Helen Zimmern):

When I analyze the process that is expressed in the sentence, 'I think,' I find a whole series of daring assertions, the argumentative proof of which would be difficult, perhaps impossible: for instance, that it is I who think, that there must necessarily be something that thinks, that thinking is an activity and operation on the part of a being who is thought of as a cause, that there is an 'ego,' and finally, that it is already determined what is to be designated by thinking—that I KNOW what thinking is.

But there are numerous conceptions of what could fill this concept of "I." The phrase "I think therefore I am" (cogito, ergo sum) does not supply the answer.
Many other questions on this site ask what the "I" is. But for instance, and sticking to what Descartes might have meant, Nietzsche seems to understand Descartes to have meant that the "I" is whatever causes and experiences the thought — a primary cause. This is counter to Nietzsche's view of the "I" as resulting from the Will to Power.

But what is and what represents that entity? Is it the body? Is it a feeling? Is it both? Also, why is “I think” the same as “I am experiencing a thought”? The former seems to involve an active action and the latter seems more passive

Nietzsche seems to be stating a thought that was voiced by Kant and before him by Hume. The cogito assumes the concept of "I" without justification. Hume espoused the bundle theory: what we call things are bundles of perceptions. For Hume this is true even of our own selves, so what I call "I" is not an entity but a bundle of perceptions and memories. David Hume, A Treatise on Human Nature, Book 1, Part IV, Section VI.

"The "I" means the entity experiencing the thought, and under some readings, the entity causing the thought." This is interesting. Can you quote Descartes to support this?

See Meditations on First Philosophy (1641), I (meaning one):

SEVERAL years have now elapsed since I first became aware that I had accepted, even from my youth, many false opinions for true,[...]

As we can see the "I" is there since the beginning. The Med starts with a critical analysis of (received) knowledge, opinions, perception, dreams, in search for the "mark of certainty".
All the above are sort of "actions" presupposing an agent: the thinking subject.
The cogito is not the conclusion of an argument but the expression of intuition: my experience of doubt is the evidence that there is a subject formulating that thought (an "actor") , and this subject is myself.

+1 This is the context that is set up by Descartes and in which cogito sum needs to be interpreted. Descartes simply starts with his own experiences and reflections - in a deliberately phenomenological manner, trying to not prejudge what consciousness is or how it works. So there is, at least initially, no "mystery" of "what is this I".

@mudskipper: But if the "I" is presupposed to exist, then just what does the cogito purport to prove? It sounds circular to me.

@Kevin The Cogito doesn't prove anything. We don't know what "I" is nor what "think" is. Essentially, we cannot know, undeniably, any useful thing. That is why Descartes, as others following him, had to add in other axioms in order to proceed. It is important not because of what it proves, but what we can say is left after applying doubt.

OP: "Descartes famously said the above phrase but what exactly is the “I” here supposed to represent?"
What is Descartes' "I" really supposed to be?
Per Heidegger's mileage, Descartes' phrase needs development to stand firmly, otherwise it has no basis to subsequently connect to body or world except by the grace of God, e.g.

Descartes’ claim that these perceptions [i.e. mind-body distinction & connection] are clear and distinct
indicates that the mind cannot help but believe them true, and so they
must be true for otherwise God would be a deceiver, which is
impossible. IEP: Mind-Body
Relation

For ontological rigour the 'thinker' needs further qualification: If he exists he must exist somewhere.

If the 'cogito sum' is to serve as the point of departure for the
existential analytic of Dasein, then it needs to be turned around, and
furthermore its content needs new ontologico-phenomenal confirmation.
The 'sum' is then asserted first, and indeed in the sense that "I am
in a world".
SZ 211


If, in the ontology of Dasein, we 'take our departure'
from a worldless "I" in order to provide this "I" with an Object and
an ontologically baseless relation to that Object, then we have
'presupposed' not too much, but too little. SZ 315-6

∴ Descartes cogito, the "I", can be understood as the unitary phenomenon, being-in-the-world.

The compound expression 'Being-in-the-world' indicates in the very way
we have coined it, that it stands for a unitary phenomenon. This
primary datum must be seen as a whole. But while Being-in-the-world
cannot be broken up into contents which may be pieced together, this
does not prevent it from having several constitutive items in
its structure. SZ 53

What Descartes uncovers is not a bare "I" but an I that exists … somewhere. So although he doesn't realise it, he actually discovers the world too at this point.  Albeit a barely defined world, but a world in which the entities of nature can be discovered.

To say that the "I" exists somewhere, "in the world", seems a petitio principii. There is, initially, after putting everything in doubt, no reason to assume the "I" is anywhere. It could be literally everywhere, or not in any place. There is no concept of "space" yet.  It's only after "discovering" the Other (the idea of the infinite) that anything else is found (namely, that Other). (But then the whole world gets smuggled in again... which is not so convincing perhaps...)

@mudskipper Yes, Heidegger is looking ahead to the external relation problem and solves it by taking the "point of departure" as the inseparable being-in-the-world. The world in this case is exceedingly vague and the most 'outer' concept. But actually it should not be considered separately. It "would come closer to the phenomenal content if we were to say that Dasein is the Being of this 'between' [between subject & world]. Yet to take our orientation from this 'between' would still be misleading." SZ 132

. . . "For with such an orientation we would also be covertly assuming the entities between which this "between", as such, 'is', and we would be doing so in a way which is ontologically vague. The "between" is already conceived as the result of the convenientia of two things that are present-at-hand. But to assume these beforehand always splits the phenom­enon asunder, and there is no prospect of putting it together again from the fragments."

In a later chapter, after Heidegger has discussed the temporality (historicality) of the world, he pulls the phenomenon together in this statement: "That inside which existing Dasein understands itself, is ‘there’ along with its factical existence. That inside which one primarily understands oneself has Dasein’s kind of Being. Dasein is its world existingly." SZ 364

Descartes himself defines the 'I' as the thing doing the thinking.
Here is the French version.

Je n'admets maintenant rien qui ne soit nécessairement vrai : je ne suis donc, précisément parlant, qu'une chose qui pense, c'est-à-dire un esprit, un entendement ou une raison, qui sont des termes dont la signification m'était auparavant inconnue. Or je suis une chose vraie, et vraiment existante ; mais quelle chose ? Je l'ai dit : une chose qui pense. -- René Descartes, Les méditations (1641)

My English translation:

I now admit nothing that is not necessarily true: I am therefore, precisely speaking, only a thinking thing, that is, a mind, an understanding, or a reason, terms whose signification was until now unknown to me. I am, however, a real thing, and truly existent; but what thing? I have said it: a thinking thing.

So, the 'I' in Descartes' Cogito does not refer in particular to the person of Descartes or to his self.
It is clear that the many critiques of the Cogito never bothered to read Descartes.

How I understand this, and my French is, admittedly, a bit rusty, is that he doesn't want to commit (yet) under what substance this something (chose) falls. But I can't see how you can deny that the "I" is not still Descartes... Descartes simply identifies as a thinking something.

+1 There is an ambiguity in Descartes, and imo @Speakpigeon definitely has a point here. If the word "I" in "I think, therefore I exist" refers to the historical person Descartes, then, obviously that statement is false (since Descartes died a long time ago, unless we believe his soul still survived and is still thinking). On the other hand, if it doesn't refer to the historical person, then the whole text becomes inconsistent -- in particular the preamble (which Mauro Allegranza pointed at) then seems disconnected from the contentual meditation. Jaakko Hintikka studied exactly this ambiguity.

So, the meditation in a way can only make sense if it's re-enacted by the readers... (Hintikka also analyses this logic. The "cogito sum" is according to him not an inference, but a performance. I'd say: in the reader, a re-enactment.)

@mudskipper "The "cogito sum" is according to him [Hintikka] not an inference, but a performance." I didn't know that, but I say exactly this in one of my answers on the Cogito. The Cogito is performative. When you think the Cogito, you think, so you exist, and it is for each of us the try it for ourselves. But the point is still not the logic of it. We don't need to prove to ourselves (let alone to anyone else) that we exist. It is just an observation: Ah, I am thinking . . . right, so, I am. But to do that, we have to know that we are thinking. Presumably, most people do, now and then.

@Philomath "he doesn't want to commit (yet) under what substance this something (chose) falls." You read in dead people's minds?! What he did do is to say that the 'I' is the thing that does the thinking. - 2. "But I can't see how you can deny that the "I" is not still Descartes...*" I didn't say that. I said that Descartes himself defined what he meant by the 'I' as the thing that does the thinking. - 3. "Descartes simply identifies as a thinking something" The name we give to people we give it to their public persona, not to the thing that does their thinking.

@Speakpigeon   La nature m'enseigne aussi par ces sentiments de douleur, de faim, de soif, etc., que je ne suis pas seulement logé dans mon corps, ainsi qu'un pilote en son navire, mais, outre cela, que je lui suis conjoint très étroitement et tellement confondu et mêlé, que je compose comme un seul tout avec lui.

The "I" is defined by the experience of thinking. Thats the point.
Note that the "I" is not what is defined as the experience of thinking. Experience of thinking is not "I". "I" is what experienced the thinking.
If you feel cold then you are not the cold. You feel something, therefore you exist. If you dont exist you cannot feel anything.

"I'm freezing therefore I am!" (A polar bear ;-) ). Happy Christmas.

Descartes used a variety of ways and several occasions to describe his thoughts on the relationship between thinking and existence. A number of them are quoted and referred to here.
If the quoted statements were intended as proofs of anything, it is hard not to see some degree of vulnerability to criticism through their circularity or question-begging, clearly undermining any evidential value on any existential question.  Thus, any reference to 'I' or a thinker or someone who feels already presupposes the existence of whoever or whatever is referred to: and the perception of this circularity is hardly a new criticism.
It may perhaps be, that Descartes was not really aiming at any proof of anything through what has to be an invalid line of argument. His intent could perhaps alternatively have been to explore the characteristics and natural features involved in thinking and feeling?

The "I" in the quote "I think, therefore I am" is paradoxical.
Because the conclusion is "I am", this implies that the existence of the "I" was not a hypothesis but only a conclusion.
In that case, "I" cannot be used in the phrase "I think" because the existence of the "I" has not been determined at that point.
Hence a paradox.
PS  This completely ignores major important issues about what it means to be an individual to be an "I", issues which are best left for another occasion.

Our understanding of the universe implies perceiving change, causality, time, etc. by means of interactions.
While all electronic phenomena occurs at the same time when we plug a radio, we cannot assess its function and structure as such. We need to analyze all the circuit by means of atomic interactions. For example: the power source provides n Volts and it is connected to the power switch, the switch to the fuse, etc.
An interaction is an exchange of contents between two systems, whether it is metaphysical or physical, whether it is chemical, electrical or ideal. For example, in the metaphysical realm, when you assess f(x)=2x, you, as observer, are providing a content (the value of x) to the function, and it returns a value to you. In the physical realm, when you push a door, you are exerting an action and getting a reaction (opposite force) in response. In the quantum-physical realm, fundamental interactions are described by Feynman diagrams, etc.
Now, in all interactions where an observer is present, one is ALWAYS the subject, and the other is always the object. The subject can be a rock, an equation, a number or a feeling. And the subject is always, as colloquially named, me, that is, ...
I.


If you want to problematize the subject in the phrase „cogito ergo
sum = je pense donc je suis“ you may take it as the experience of
being self-conscious linked to the experience of thinking or
questioning.
In modern, a bit technically language it means: To have a self-model which displays
the modus of thinking.

Since we know about the mental disorder of personal dissociation, we also
know that self-consciousness is an achievement of the mental
processes within a healthy person. There definitely exist mental
states where one cannot rely on the self-model.



The "I" exposes the following traits:

It thinks. (This one is explicit.)
It is aware of itself and capable of reflection, because it makes observations about itself and puts them in language. (This is quite obvious but implicit.)
It has state, i.e. memory. This is not quite as obvious; but reflexion is a recursion which refers to a (however slightly) previous state. Each mental loop needs a finite amount of time; each recursion level is a different state than the previous one, which therefore must be retained. The state of a person having an original thought is different from the person realizing that they had a thought, but (at least partially) contained in it.

Together we can say that these traits define consciousness and identity: Intelligence, self-awareness and a known past.
This is all we can infer though from this ontological "bootstrapping". For example, it says nothing about the "other" that is not "I" — the borders of this entity are undefined. It could be an all-encompassing god or a brain in a vat. Both would be intelligent entities with an identity.


what exactly does Descartes mean here by “I”?

Descartes is simply using it as a pronoun in the same way that most sentences using "I" in the subject use it.
From Collins Dictionary:
1. The person speaking or writing: personal pronoun in the first person singular. I is the nominative form, me the objective, mine the possessive, and myself the reflexive and intensive; my is the possessive pronominal adjective.

But what is and what represents that entity? Is it the body? Is it a feeling? Is it both?

It is however you perceive yourself, (the "I") to be.

Also, why is “I think” the same as “I am experiencing a thought”? The former seems to involve an active action and the latter seems more passive.

Your observation is correct, they are very similar but not the same.  For more information here is a link to active vs passive writing.
Noli plus legere in sententiam quam ibi
